# Converting Curl Array JSON Post to Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, curl, post

I am trying to convert

```
curl -d '[[51.3, 13.4], [51.4, 13.3]]' -XPOST  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  https://elevation.racemap.com/api
```

Curl command into Python. I tried

```
import urllib.request
import json      

body = {'locs': [[51.3, 13.4], [51.4, 13.3]]}
myurl = "https://elevation.racemap.com/api"
req = urllib.request.Request(myurl)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
jsondata = json.dumps(body)
jsondataasbytes = jsondata.encode('utf-8')   
req.add_header('Content-Length', len(jsondataasbytes))
print (jsondataasbytes)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, jsondataasbytes)
```

which gives an error. It seems curl does not specify parameter name while passing an array? I am not sure how to form the Json to fit the curl input.

Comment: "an error" is the worst of all errors, since nobody can help you with it. Please add a detailed error description including the full error traceback.

Comment: You can paste your curl command into https://curlconverter.com/ and it will convert it to Python code using Requests for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply just use [`requests`](https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/):

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = '[[51.3, 13.4], [51.4, 13.3]]'

response = requests.post('https://elevation.racemap.com/api', headers=headers, data=data)

print(response.status_code)
# 200
```